# What the valid range of HSV color

Tags: javascript, colors, hsv

I'm playing with HSV color. I have an array of hsv after convert from rgb color:

```
//hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]
var hsv = rgbToHsv(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

I will add or subtract it

```
hsv[0] += ...
hsv[1] += ...
hsv[2] += ...
```

And I need to valid the value before convert it back to rgb. What is the valid range of hsv?

Here is the function I using to convert rgb to hsv

```
function rgbToHsv(r, g, b) {  
    var r = (r / 255),  
         g = (g / 255),  
     b = (b / 255);   
    var min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b),  
        max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b),  
        delta = max - min;  
    var value = max,  
        saturation,  
        hue;  
    // Hue  
    if (max == min) {  
        hue = 0;  
    } else if (max == r) {  
        hue = (60 * ((g-b) / (max-min))) % 360;  
    } else if (max == g) {  
        hue = 60 * ((b-r) / (max-min)) + 120;  
    } else if (max == b) {  
        hue = 60 * ((r-g) / (max-min)) + 240;  
    }  
    if (hue < 0) {  
        hue += 360;  
    }  
    // Saturation  
    if (max == 0) {  
        saturation = 0;  
    } else {  
        saturation = 1 - (min/max);  
    }  
    return [(hue), (saturation * 100), (value * 100)];  
}
```

Comment: In the interval [0, 1] ⊂ ℝ, but that may be mapped to 0..255.

Comment: what implementation of rgbToHsv are you using? it's as @Joey says, it can be a float value between 0 and 1, or an integer between 0 and 255 (where 1f represents 255).

Comment: @Uttara: Your answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Roughly the same algorithm is used for [this online converter](https://www.tlbx.app/color-converter). You can check the article after for the opposite conversion.

H is definitely between 0 and 360, but regarding S and V it is different. Like most values for color conversion or color blending mode calculation, a float between 0 and 1 is used. I would say it is better because beeing a float means you can have all the levels of precision you want.

Now it is not uncommon (like on this online converter and your current javascript) to multiply it by 100 to get a percentage. Often rounded as well. What is important to understand with this rounding is that obviously it increases the chances of you getting a different RGB color if you convert back and forth `rgb > hsv > rgb`. If this is important, then you're better with the floats.

Since you are asking what is "valid", I would say it only depends on how you want to use it or where these numbers will be used.